# json data fetching android

Tags: android, json

How do I fetch this data using json. I have tried this but not working. Im very much confused about how to fetch the below data. Any help appreciated

```
    {
    "sftid": [
        "sfta"
    ],
    "todate": 205618.268,
    "today": 5307.174,
    "sfta": 5093.717,
    "sftb": 213.457,
    "sftc": 0,
    "cropday": 21,
    "crushingday": 21,
    "vtractor": 4535.075,
    "vtruck": 532.687,
    "vbcart": 239.412,
    "yestitons": 6374,
    "ytractor": 248,
    "ytruck": 90,
    "ybcart": 40,
    "ycart": 48,
    "hr1": 515.043,
    "hr2": 625.651,
    "hr3": 706.789,
    "hr4": 626.796,
    "hr5": 630.639,
    "hr6": 608.053,
    "hr7": 604.559,
    "hr8": 776.187
}


 JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jsonObj = jobject.getJSONObject("todate");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
 JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
```

then

```
double todate = jobject.getDouble("todate");
and so on as per the data type
```

or simply you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which will help you to convert your json data to a model class which you can use to fetch the data easily.
For this you need to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.
So suppose you created class with above link as `"Myresponse"` the you can use it as

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Myresponse data = gson.fromJson("<your json resopnse>",Myresponse.class);
```

I have added screenshot for the settings you need to do on jsonschema2pojo website
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you see your response contains one JSONObject which contains many elements, First element is an JSONArray rest can be taken as a double/String.
It goes as follows :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray sftid_array = json.getJSONArray("sftid");

ArrayList<String> sftid = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < sftid_array; i++) {
   sfid.put(sftid_array.getString(i));
}
double todate = json.getDouble("todate");
double today = json.getDouble("today");
double sfta = json.getDouble("sfta");
double sftb = json.getDouble("sftb");
.
.
.
and so on
```

You can also use Array to store data of JSONArray. Don't forget to put it in try catch as it may throw JSONException.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONObject jsonObj = jobject.getJSONObject("todate");
```

Comment: JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                                JSONObject jsonObj = jobject.getJSONObject("todate");
                                date = jsonObj.getString("todate");
                                txt_date.setText(date);  This isnt working

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar sorry, I made a mistake, plz see my edited.